# Calling class function without objects

Tags: c++, static

The following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class ABC
{
    public:
    void display ()
    {   
        cout<<"ehhh";
    }
};


int main ()
{
  using xyz = ABC;
  xyz::display();
  
}
```

Throws an error:
main.cpp:19:16: error: cannot call member function ‘void ABC::display()’ without object

But if I change the function to static it works and gives output.

```
static void display ()
    {   
        cout<<"ehhh";
    }
```

I understand static members are initialized automatically, what's happening here ?

Comment: When `static` is used in a class function definition, it means that no object of the class is required to use it, which is basically what you are trying to do here, it seems.

Comment: The line `using xyz = ABC;` What should that do in your eyes?

Comment: The line you are talking about is just to change the namespace to ABC. Calling a function requires creation of an object. You can think of it as assigning xyz as an alias for ABC and nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling a non-static function of a class requires creation of an object.
You can call the function using the code by creating an object or by declaring the function as static.

```
// Calling display function by creating an object.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class ABC
{
    public:
    void display ()
    {
        cout<<"ehhh";
    }
};


int main ()
{
  using xyz = ABC;
  xyz obj; // You can also write --> ABC obj;
  obj.display();
}
```

```
// Calling display function by declaring the member function as static
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class ABC
{
    public:
    static void display ()
    {
        cout<<"ehhh";
    }
};


int main ()
{
  using xyz = ABC;
  xyz::display(); // You can also use ABC::display();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But if I change the function to static it works and gives output.

The meaning of `static` when applied to a member is that [the member is not bound to class instances](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static). For member functions, that means two things. First, the `this` pointer is not available inside the function definition. Second, the function can be called without an object.
So, yes, changing the function to be `static` does allow it to be called without an object.

In contrast, a non-static member function must be called through an object of the class. Otherwise, there is no way to define the `this` pointer. (The `this` pointer is available in every non-static member function, even if the pointer is not used.)

If a non-`virtual` member function does not use the `this` pointer, I would be inclined to make the function `static`. This helps convey the fact that the function has no dependency on a particular object, and it might make the function easier to use (as you have already discovered). Keep in mind that sometimes `this` is used without explicitly writing "`this`". For example, if there is a data member named `a`, then inside a member function a line like `a = 0` is short for `this->a = 0`. A quick way to see if the `this` pointer is used in a member function is to make the function `static` and see if the compiler complains. If it doesn't complain, I tend to leave the function `static`.

> I understand static members are initialized automatically, what's happening here ?

Your understanding is off, as there is no automatic initialization.

A static member is not bound to class instances. For data members, that means that there is a single value stored somewhere. If one object changes that value, then all other objects see the changed value. (In fact, the value can be seen and changed without having an object available.)

This is not about initialization but about lifetime and number of instances. A static data member is constructed/initialized before the `main` function starts and is destroyed after the `main` function ends. It is not initialized within the constructor of the class; an attempt to do so is likely an error. (Perhaps this is the origin of the "initialized automatically" misconception?) There is only one instance of a static data member, regardless of how many objects of the class exist – even if no objects of the class are ever created.

Answer (score 0):

Object  creation is compulsory for  the non-static functions.The non-static functions are object/instance base functions  and have different behavior for every different  instances(objects). separate Memory is allocated  to every different object.while  in case of  static static-functions are  the class Functions and always get initialized in memory only once.